# Select products of a certain category and brand

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quert where i want to select all products that have the category and brand selected on url:

> http://localhost/www.fermaster.pt/listaProdutos/category1/brand-1

```
"SELECT prod.*
 FROM produtos as prod
 INNER JOIN categorias as cat
    ON cat.nomeCategoria LIKE '".$categoria."'
 INNER JOIN marcas as m
    ON m.nomeCategoria LIKE '".$marca."'
 WHERE prod.categoriaProduto = cat.ID
    AND prod.marcaProduto = m.ID"
```

It gives me the error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'nomeProduto' in C:\wamp\www\www.fermaster.pt\pages\listaProdutos.php on line 32

The full code is:

```
<?php
$db = new Database();    
$db->connect();


if(isset($marca))
{
    echo 'Produto - Categoria - Marca';
    $db->sql("SELECT prod.*
              FROM produtos as prod
              INNER JOIN categorias as cat
                ON cat.nomeCategoria LIKE '".$categoria."'
              INNER JOIN marcas as m
                ON m.nomeCategoria LIKE '".$marca."'
              WHERE prod.categoriaProduto = cat.ID
                    AND prod.marcaProduto = m.ID");
}
else
{
    echo 'Produto - Categoria';
    $db->sql("SELECT prod.*
              FROM produtos as prod
              INNER JOIN categorias as cat
                ON cat.nomeCategoria LIKE '".$categoria."'
              WHERE prod.categoriaProduto = cat.ID");
}

$res = $db->getResult();

foreach($res as $output)
{
    echo '<br />'.$output['nomeProduto'];
}
```

?>

Comment: That error means that `$output['nomeProduto'];` does not exist in the array/object

Comment: You should do `print_r($res);` right before your foreach statement and see what your results are and post them here. This will print the results as a readable array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to escape the string first because of the `/` elements. MySQLs `QUOTE()` function is your friend here. Check the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) on that topic.